# Why this Lambda Expression is casted as MemberExpression and UnaryExpression?

Tags: c#, lambda

I am new to c# and lambda expressions; in [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/784331/WPF-MVVM-Validation-ViewModel-using-IDataErrorInfo) tutorial I cannot understand what the code does with this Lambda expression:

```
public ViewModel()
{
    base.AddRule(() => Aid, () =>
    Aid.Length >= (5 * 2) &&
    Aid.Length <= (16 * 2) &&
    Aid.Length % 2 == 0, "Invalid AID.");
}
```

And this is the `AddRule` Method which the tutorial says it adds the rule to the rule dictionary:

```
public void AddRule<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression, Func<bool> ruleDelegate, string errorMessage)
{
    var name = GetPropertyName(expression);

    ruleMap.Add(name, new Binder(ruleDelegate, errorMessage));
}
```

and

```
protected static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
        {
            if (expression == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");

            Expression body = expression.Body;
            MemberExpression memberExpression = body as MemberExpression;
            if (memberExpression == null)
            {
                memberExpression = (MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)body).Operand;
            }
            return memberExpression.Member.Name;
        }

    }
```

What does the `() => Aid` mean and why the `addrule` receives it and cast it as UnaryExpression and MemberExpression ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`() => Aid` is shorthand for `() => { return Aid; }`, which returns a property (or field - you didn't show its declaration). Normally this results in an anonymous function.

But because the `AddRule` method takes an `Expression<Func<T>>` instead of a `Func<T>`, the compiler creates instructions that create an AST (abstract syntax tree) instead of an anonymous function. An AST can be compiled into a method, but here it's only used to extract the name of the property/field.

The alternative is to pass the property name as a string. The advantage of using a member expression is that it's refactor-friendly: renaming the property will also update this code, ensuring that the rule is still associated with the right property.

This is what is actually being passed into `AddRule` (you can do this manually, but you'd lose the refactor-friendly benefit - besides, `() => Aid` is a lot more concise):

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<T>>(
    Expression.Property(
        Expression.Constant(this),
        "Aid"));
```

Comment: So, the GetPropertyName simply returns the name of property in this case "Aid"; right?

Comment: Exactly. Note that C# 6 introduces the `nameof` operator, which makes all of this a lot easier: the compiler will transform `nameof(Aid)` into `"Aid"`, giving you the same benefit without the hassle of inspecting expressions.

Answer (score 5):

A MemberExpression is an expression on an instance or a static expression for a MemberInfo.

An UnaryExpression is an expression that revolves around a target and a single operator (see definition for the term unary). One good example of such an operator is a cast. Another is an operation to box or unbox a value type.

So why does the example to get a MemberInfo need to handle an UnaryExpression?

Consider

```
public class Foo
{
    public String RefType { get; set; }
    public int ValueType { get; set; }
}
```

and some code

```
Expression<Func<Foo, object>> getter;
getter = f => f.RefType // compiler emits MemberExpression for RefType on a Foo instance
getter = f => f.ValueType // compiler emits an UnaryExpression to Box a MemberExpression for ValueType on a Foo instance.
```

Answer (score 1):

`Aid` is a property of the viewmodel used in that example:

```
    public string Aid
    {
        get { return Get(() => Aid); }
        set { Set(() => Aid, value); }
    }
```

You can check this if you download the entire project from that article (link is on the top)

When you pass a property to a lambda expression, it will be represented by MemberExpression. This class is dedicated for this as described in [MemberExpression Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.memberexpression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)